# How to match for the first letter is uppercase / capital letter in php?

Tags: php, regex, uppercase

i am currently building a regex to match or find any word starting with capital letter for the first letter.

result to return : "Apple", not "apple"

This is the code i've build but it is wrong because it also takes apple in the result. Please help.

```
$count = preg_match_all("/(\bAp)[a-z]\w+(le)/i",$value,$match);
```

Comment: Do you want to only make sure the first letter is case sensitive and the rest is not? You may use `/\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*\b/u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are making your regex case insensitive by following it by `/i`. Remove the `/i` and it will work fine.

To read more about flags in regex follow the link [Advanced searching with flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags)

Comment: ic. so the problem is /i. i've remove the /i and yeah..it works!!! $count = preg_match_all("/(\bAp)[a-z]\w+(le)/",$value,$match); Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $count = preg_match_all('/(?<=\s)[A-Z]\w+/','test Apple apple2 Orange orange2',$match);
print_r($match);
```